# Unable to select Variable to set date values in SCD type 2 , SSIS

Tags: datetime, ssis, scd, scd2

I am creating a SCD type 2 dimension. In my destination table there are start time and d]end date columns. I am unable to select the **variable to set date values** in the SSIS package. Is this something I should configure in the SSIS package? If so, how?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the 'variable to set date values' input box, and use **SCROLL THE WHEEL MOUSE** to change between variables.

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous comment said - click on the Variable to set date values field and use your scroll wheel (In my case, I couldn't see that field until I resized the window).

And speaking in SCD context, System::StartTime should be the variable to use here, because all inserted data(or updated) will have the same ValidFrom date.